# Dynamics CreateEntityRequest - assign entity to a display area

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to create a new entity and have it appear in the 'My Finances' and 'Personal Assets' areas.

I am able to create the entity without problems using CreateEntityRequest.

If I create the entity manually I get a list of the variuos areas where I can display the entity.

How can I do the same thing programmatically?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able do get this to work using the Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.IsvReadiness.SupportingItems.SiteMap class that comes with the SDK in conjunction with ExportXmlRequest and ImportXmlRequest.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Please mark your or my answer as the actual answer to your question, so it won't show up as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to manipulate the SiteMap to do that; that's not something that's done in the metadata of the entity itself.